# Strange!!, Textview value is updating from background thread

Tags: multithreading, android

Today, Something strange thing happen when I was playing with random things.My code is shown bellow,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                    textView.setText("Hello I am fine" +i);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello I am fine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName)).setText("Hello");

    }
```

This code works fine, but technically it shouldn't work. **Because we can't update UI from the thread**, I cannot understand why this code is working. Please tell me why this code is working.

But when I ass toast in thread it starts crashing, so my question is why textview update from thread is working.

Thank you

Comment: You should check on Android OS higher than 3.0

Comment: I have tried on every version, but it si working, but technically it should not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update ui from a background thread. Use `runOnUIThread`.

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     textView.setText("Hello I am fine" +i);
     textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   }
  });
```

Quoting from the docs

Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View objects; this thread is called the UI thread. Only objects running on the UI thread have access to other objects on that thread.

Comment: but this code is working that's problem but it shouldn't working

Comment: @NixitPatel you should get an exception does your thread start. also why do you have this `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName)).setText("Hello")` after start?

Comment: @NixitPatel if you thread actually runs you will get an exception.

Comment: @NixitPatel try putting Thread.sleep before setting text to textview and check it on device

Comment: @NixitPatel did you try it on a device coz i do get an exception. on emulator i had to put thread.sleep(1000) and the exception is thrown